# Yii2 GridView filter date by year

Tags: gridview, yii2, filtering

This question is simple, but in Yii2 I cannot find the solution.

Given a birthday field, how is it possible in gridview to filter by year?  Typically in an index gridview.

Comment: This is what I was looking :)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you are looking  for something like this:

add in to your model

```
public static function getYearsList()
{
    $years = (new Query())->select('DISTINCT YEAR(`birthday`) as years')->from('{{%yourTable}}')->column();
    return array_combine($years, $years);
}
```

and then in gridview

```
[
    'attribute' => 'birthday',
    'filter' => YourModel::getYearsList(),
]
```

And then in your search model add `andFilterWhere()` to compare *birthday* with year. It can look like this:

```
$query->andFilterWhere('YEAR(`birthday`)' => $year);
```

Comment: Thank @Tony, No this is not useful. Is not so simple.  I need a real filter on date field mapped from database by activeRecord.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question then, please. Because all that answerer has now, is an assumptions about what you actually have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have i date field (birthday) in a model based by activeRecord in mysql datatabase dateTime field. In looking for a way for filter in gridview the rows  by the year only, and then show only the person born in a specific year.