# Search date field only with year in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I've a table admission_date. I want to have a grid where that field can be searched by date. As of Now I've to put entire date to search the row. But I want filter students by year. I've seen similar question at [Yii2 GridView filter date by year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193794/yii2-gridview-filter-date-by-year)

However couldn't find where they have initialized the $year which they have mentioned in searchModel.

Please help me.
Arun

edited:

### Model (StudentsDetails.php)

class StudentsDetails extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName() {
    return 'students_details';
}

public $year;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['admission_date', 'date_of_birth', 'slc_year', 'hsc_year','year'], 'safe'],
        [['program', 'roll_no'], 'integer'],
        [['address'], 'string'],
        [['parent_annual_income', 'slc_total_mark', 'slc_percent', 'hsc_total_mark', 'hsc_percent'], 'number'],
        [['regid', 'shift', 'landline', 'city'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
        [['student_name', 'parent_name'], 'string', 'max' => 75],
        [['gender', 'blood_group'], 'string', 'max' => 8],
        [['mobile'], 'string', 'max' => 12],
        [['district', 'province', 'country', 'parent_relation', 'parent_occupation', 'parent_contact', 'slc_board', 'hsc_board'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        [['slc_school', 'hsc_school'], 'string', 'max' => 120],
        [['slc_symbol', 'hsc_symbol'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
        [['section', 'semester'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
        [['program'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Programs::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['program' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'regid' => 'Regid',
        'admission_date' => 'Admission',
        'program' => 'Program',
        'shift' => 'Shift',
        'student_name' => 'Name',
        'date_of_birth' => 'Date Of Birth',
        'gender' => 'Gender',
        'blood_group' => 'Blood Group',
        'landline' => 'Landline',
        'mobile' => 'Mobile',
        'address' => 'Address',
        'city' => 'City',
        'district' => 'District',
        'province' => 'Province',
        'country' => 'Country',
        'parent_name' => 'Parent Name',
        'parent_relation' => 'Parent Relation',
        'parent_occupation' => 'Parent Occupation',
        'parent_annual_income' => 'Parent Annual Income',
        'parent_contact' => 'Parent Contact',
        'slc_school' => 'Slc School',
        'slc_board' => 'Slc Board',
        'slc_symbol' => 'Slc Symbol',
        'slc_year' => 'Slc Year',
        'slc_total_mark' => 'Slc Total Mark',
        'slc_percent' => 'Slc Percent',
        'hsc_school' => 'Hsc School',
        'hsc_board' => 'Hsc Board',
        'hsc_symbol' => 'Hsc Symbol',
        'hsc_year' => 'Hsc Year',
        'hsc_total_mark' => 'Hsc Total Mark',
        'hsc_percent' => 'Hsc Percent',
        'roll_no' => 'Roll',
        'section' => 'Section',
        'semester' => 'Semester',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getProgram0() {
    return $this->hasOne(Programs::className(), ['id' => 'program']);
}

public static function getYearsList() {
    $years = (new Query())->select('DISTINCT YEAR(`admission_date`) as years')->from('{{%students_details}}')->column();
    return array_combine($years, $years);
}
```

### }

Search Model (StudentsDetailsSearch.php)

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\StudentsDetails;

/**
 * StudentsDetailsSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\StudentsDetails`.
 */

class StudentsDetailsSearch extends StudentsDetails {

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['id', 'program', 'roll_no'], 'integer'],
        [['regid', 'admission_date', 'shift', 'student_name', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'blood_group', 'landline', 'mobile', 'address', 'city', 'district', 'province', 'country', 'parent_name', 'parent_relation', 'parent_occupation', 'parent_contact', 'slc_school', 'slc_board', 'slc_symbol', 'slc_year', 'hsc_school', 'hsc_board', 'hsc_symbol', 'hsc_year', 'section', 'semester'], 'safe'],
        [['parent_annual_income', 'slc_total_mark', 'slc_percent', 'hsc_total_mark', 'hsc_percent'], 'number'],
    ];
}
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios() {
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params) {
    $query = StudentsDetails::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'admission_date' => $this->admission_date,
        'program' => $this->program,
        'date_of_birth' => $this->date_of_birth,
        'parent_annual_income' => $this->parent_annual_income,
        'slc_year' => $this->slc_year,
        'slc_total_mark' => $this->slc_total_mark,
        'slc_percent' => $this->slc_percent,
        'hsc_year' => $this->hsc_year,
        'hsc_total_mark' => $this->hsc_total_mark,
        'hsc_percent' => $this->hsc_percent,
        'roll_no' => $this->roll_no,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'regid', $this->regid])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'shift', $this->shift])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'student_name', $this->student_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'gender', $this->gender])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'blood_group', $this->blood_group])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'landline', $this->landline])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'mobile', $this->mobile])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $this->address])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'city', $this->city])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'district', $this->district])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'province', $this->province])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country', $this->country])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_name', $this->parent_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_relation', $this->parent_relation])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_occupation', $this->parent_occupation])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_contact', $this->parent_contact])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slc_school', $this->slc_school])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slc_board', $this->slc_board])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slc_symbol', $this->slc_symbol])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'hsc_school', $this->hsc_school])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'hsc_board', $this->hsc_board])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'hsc_symbol', $this->hsc_symbol])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'section', $this->section])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'semester', $this->semester]);
          //  ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'year(admission_date)', $year]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

### }

GridView

```
<?php


echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            //'id',
            // 'regid',
            [
                'value' => 'regid',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'attribute' => 'regid',
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'regid'],
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'admission_date',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'attribute' => 'admission_date',
                //'filter' => \app\models\StudentsDetails::getYearsList(),
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'admission_date'],
            ],
            //  'admission_date',
            //'program',
            //'shift',
            'student_name',
            // 'date_of_birth',
            // 'gender',
            // 'blood_group',
            // 'landline',
            [
                'value' => 'mobile',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'attribute' => 'mobile',
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'mobile'],
            ],
            'semester',
            'section',
            'roll_no',
            // 'address:ntext',
            // 'city',
            // 'district',
            // 'province',
            // 'country',
            // 'parent_name',
            // 'parent_relation',
            // 'parent_occupation',
            // 'parent_annual_income',
            // 'parent_contact',
            // 'slc_school',
            // 'slc_board',
            // 'slc_symbol',
            // 'slc_year',
            // 'slc_total_mark',
            // 'slc_percent',
            // 'hsc_school',
            // 'hsc_board',
            // 'hsc_symbol',
            // 'hsc_year',
            // 'hsc_total_mark',
            // 'hsc_percent',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view} {delete} {edit}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'view' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['studentview', 'sid' => $key]);
                    },
                            'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['studentdelete', 'sid' => $key], [
                                    'title' => \Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                                    'data-confirm' => \Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure to delete this item?'),
                                    'data-method' => 'post',
                        ]);
                    },
                            'edit' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['studentedit', 'sid' => $key]);
                        ;
                    }
                        ]],
                //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                ],
            ]);
                ?>
```

Comment: they have not initialized $year in searchModel they have put that in model and `$query->andFilterWhere('YEAR(`birthday`)' => $year);` in search model in `andFilterWhere()` function

Comment: update your question and show your model,  searchModel and gridView ..code

Comment: @Saurabh: can you be more specific please. How do I add that in Model

Comment: @scaisEdge: I'm explaining as my model, gridview and search model is large and wont accept in comment box. i) I have a date field called admission_date II) I tried your suggestion in other thread as mention above  III) I created function in model iv) But I couldn't find out where  this line.          $query->andFilterWhere('YEAR(`birthday`)' => $year);  Where is the $year coming from. it is uninitialized.

Comment: I think you can edit your question and add the code in question not in  comment .. comment me when done ..

Comment: @ArunKMaskey add your entire model search model in question

Comment: @scaisEdge I've added the entire Model, Search Model and Gridview.

Comment: You want filter by year the column admission_date, right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something similar you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251515/yii2-related-search-for-3-and-more-tables) 
it is about related search so you can use some of it.

Answer (score 0):

In  model remove the `$year`

In gridView  add  (uncomment) the filter for year

```
        [
            'value' => 'admission_date',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'attribute' => 'admission_date',
            'filter' => \app\models\StudentsDetails::getYearsList(),
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'admission_date'],
        ],
```

and in searchModel add (uncomment)  the search  filter `andFilterWhere( 'year(admission_date) = year (' . $this->admission_date.  ')' )`  without using like  (is not a string is a date)  and converting to year the related column

```
      $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'regid', $this->regid])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'shift', $this->shift])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'student_name', $this->student_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'gender', $this->gender])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'blood_group', $this->blood_group])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'landline', $this->landline])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'mobile', $this->mobile])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $this->address])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'city', $this->city])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'district', $this->district])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'province', $this->province])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country', $this->country])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_name', $this->parent_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_relation', $this->parent_relation])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_occupation', $this->parent_occupation])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_contact', $this->parent_contact])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slc_school', $this->slc_school])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slc_board', $this->slc_board])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slc_symbol', $this->slc_symbol])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'hsc_school', $this->hsc_school])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'hsc_board', $this->hsc_board])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'hsc_symbol', $this->hsc_symbol])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'section', $this->section])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'semester', $this->semester]);
```

Cause the andFilterWhere don't admint the where string notation then build an equivalent result this way

```
       if (isset($this->$this->admission_date)){
          $query->andWhere('year(admission_date) = year (' . $this->admission_date.  ')');
       }
```

Comment: search model gives the error.                                                                Argument 1 passed to yii\db\Query::andFilterWhere() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/balkumari/models/StudentsDetailsSearch.php on line 98 and defined.             (This is  ->andFilterWhere( 'year(admission_date) = year (' . $this->admission_date.  ')' );)

Comment: I have update the answer with a different solution for filter