# Yii2 Related table filter and sort with Grid View

Tags: sorting, gridview, filter, yii2

I had this questions part by part and solve it now so I want to share maybe someone will use it. I have 4 models: Users,Certificate, Products, Autority. The main will be Users, from users Id we see certificate, from certificate Id we si the product id, from product id we see the autority. 
I solve it in one way so maybe someone can tell me if it is good or there are some other ways to do it. This will be step by step description. :)

1)In models set links between tables (hasOne, hasMany) (this have to be in each model which have connection with next model)

```
public function getCertificate()
{   return  $this->hasOne(Certificate::className(),['id_customer' =>'id']); }
```

2) in the main table searchmodel call connection and in connection use joinWith to define the relation of your database, example:

```
$query = Users::find()
    -> where (['USERSTB.id_user' =>Yii::$app->session->get('user.idcustomer') ])
            ->joinWith('Certificate')
            ->joinWith('Certificate.Products')
            ->joinWith('Certificate.Products.Autority');
```

3) add to searchmodel public variables for each field in the attached tables, for example:

```
public $cert_description;
public $cert_autority_description;
public $cert_actdate;
public $cert_expdate;  
public $cert_domain;
```

4) add variable names in `rules()` and to field `safe`, for example:

```
public function rules()
{   return [ [ ['cert_domain','cert_description','cert_autority_description','cert_actdate','cert_expdate'], 'safe'],      ];  }
```

5)adding sort in to search method, use it under declaration of `$dataProvider`, for example:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['cert_description'] = [
    'asc' => ['products.description' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['products.description'=> SORT_DESC], ];
```

6) adding search query using andFilterWhere:

```
 ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'products.description', $this->cert_description])
```

7)And finally display data in Index GridView, on attributes that you want to view, for example:

```
 [  
    'attribute' => 'cert_description',  // !!! important to matches the name attribute
    'label'=>'Certificate',
    'value'=> 'Certificate.Products.description', 
],
```

If there is any other better method or different one I will be glad to see it. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 GridView implement Filter and Sort for Values for related Table of foreign Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509747/yii2-gridview-implement-filter-and-sort-for-values-for-related-table-of-foreign)